# Can reverse it the input with less code than these? Java

Tags: java, array

So we ask to the user to enter 10 number and then we reverse it.

```
package *;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class * {
   // n = limit of inputs 
   private static final int n = 10;
   static Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     //nkb = number from keyboard
     int [] nkb = new int[n];
     // in = number of length
     int in = nkb.length;
     //for input user
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
       System.out.println("Writte a number: ");
       nkb[i] = kb.nextInt();
     }//end for
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++){
       System.out.println("In these position "+i+" now we have these number: "+nkb[in-1-i]);
     }//end for reverse        
   }//end method
}//end class
```

It's possible to make it with less code?
I check already and they told me that we can use `List<Integer>` and call `Collections.reverse()`... but how?

Comment: You don't reverse the array. You print it in reversed order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching on the site maybe this can help.

```
for(int i = 0; i < validData.length / 2; i++) {
  int temp = validData[i];
  validData[i] = validData[validData.length - i - 1];
  validData[validData.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

[To reverse an int array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2137791/3760900)